# IA Car Drive BackWards when stuck?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

So im making a car game on unity, i want to make sure that the car will go backward if it hit a wall or something, i tried something with the rb.velocity.magnitude if its under 2, the car go backward , but im maybe missing something, thats not working good, do you have any suggestions on it ?

there is the function for driving :

```
 private void Drive() {
        currentSpeed = 2 * Mathf.PI * wheelFL.radius * wheelFL.rpm * 60 / 1000;

        if (currentSpeed < maxSpeed && !isBraking ) {
            wheelFL.motorTorque = maxMotorTorque;
            wheelFR.motorTorque = maxMotorTorque;
        } 
        else if (RB.velocity.magnitude < 2){
            Debug.Log("BackWards");
            wheelFL.motorTorque =0;
            wheelFR.motorTorque =0;
            wheelFL.motorTorque = -maxMotorTorque;
            wheelFR.motorTorque = -maxMotorTorque;
        }
        else {
            wheelFL.motorTorque = 0;
            wheelFR.motorTorque = 0;
        }
    }
```

the debug log works but the car doesnt go backward.

Comment: You need another bool like `isBreaking`.   You need `isReversing`

Comment: so the isReversing will be true if rb.vel.magnitude < 2 ? and then i can set up WheelFL and WheelFR motortoque to negative maxtorque right ?

Comment: @LeoBartkus Im not finding where my bool will work

Comment: This is for AI?

Comment: If so, I think you need a more complex check than just the velocity.  For example, it will be < 2 immediately when the car starts moving, before it has time to accelerate.  It will also be > 2 if it is reversing quickly, which might not be what you want.   I would maybe change it to check if it is < 2 continuously for 2 seconds, or use a raycast to see if something is blocking it in front.